# Использование пагинации в Angular

Tags: bootstrap, angular2

Получаю данные от сервера здесь http://swapi.co/api/people/. Мне нужно прикрутить bootstrap пагинацию.
Что лучше использовать: готовое решение типа https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-bootstrap-pagination или использовать параметры из url такие как`/?page=1`, `/?page=2` и т.д.?

Comment: Готовое решение в любом случае надо будет допилить немного. Может у кого-нибудь есть идеи на этот счет?

Comment: Неужели ни у кого нет идей? Сообщество по Angular не очень активное

Comment: Рекомендую использовать модуль ngx-pagination https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pagination . Легок в понимании и прост в настройке и кастомизации.

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под вопросом "Что лучше использовать...?" Есть какие-то конкретные требования по сложности реализации или по скорости работы, или по какой-то другой метрике?  Чего Вы хотите добиться если сами знаете какие варианты можно использовать?